# Is it possible to sanitize keys and values of an associative array without a support array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, sanitization

When I have data coming from user input (in the form of an associative array `('key'=>'value')`) that I will have to insert into a DB, what I generally do for sanitizing the **values** is:

```
<?php 
  foreach ($input as $key => &$value){ //Note the pass-by-reference
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = htmlentities($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value);
  }
?>
```

However, passing the **key** by reference is not allowed, so what I do, if I have to sanitize both keys **and** values, is:

```
<?php
  $sanitizedInput = array(); 
  foreach ($input as $key => $value){
    $key = strip_tags($key); 
    $key = htmlentities($key);
    $key = stripslashes($key);
    $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$key);
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = htmlentities($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$value);
    $sanitizedInput[$key] = $value;
  }
?>
```

Of course this works, but the beauty of the first way is that I don't need an extra array as support variable.
Is it possible to achieve the same level of simplicity also for keys sanitization but without using a support variable?

Comment: Side note: what you're doing is not in any way sane sanitisation. You're just applying random string modifications to your input. While there may be a cute little code snippet that may solve your immediate question, you're doing it entirely wrong in the big picture.

Comment: You need to look into array functions, and possibly `array_walk()` in particular

Comment: Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: @deceze : I read the article and it made things slightly clear. However what I posted is a typical case of input, saved into db, and then output as needed. So for sure htmlentities + mysqli_real_escape are needed. I don't agree with the article saying to apply escape functions when needed: according to it I should just SQL-escape the data before putting them into DB and just when I output the data, htmlescape it. In my case this is all data that will be output again, so why not do it once and for all? It's less error prone to me..

Comment: @MaggsWeb : As pointed out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#45380) , `array_walk` cannot be used to change keys.

Comment: So what if you want to search for data in the database? Input is "Me & You". Doesn't match anything in the database. Because your database actually contains "Me &amp; You". So what if you ever want to output this data somewhere other than in an HTML context? Emails you send with content from the database now contain "Me &amp; You". Data dumped to a CSV file now contains "Me &amp; You". – In short: for super narrowly defined scenarios *it doesn't cause any problems*; but can you see the future? Won't your use case ever expand? Will it *never* cause any problems or additional headaches?

Comment: Further: `<p><?php echo $data; ?></p>` - how can you be ***sure*** this doesn't cause any HTML injection? The escaping happened somewhere in an entirely different part of your code at a different time. Or maybe it didn't happen. Maybe someone entered data by hand into the database and *didn't* escape it. Well... with `<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data); ?></p>` you could be a lot more confident that you're escaping correctly.

Comment: @deceze Thanks! I didn't thought about it!

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure why you're escaping data you insert in the dbase.  Better to use prepared statements with bound parameters to insert the user submitted data, then sanitize the data as it comes out.  When it comes out you can apply your sanitizing function using array_map() to sanitize everything coming out all at once.